# How to shape displayed data from MSql table after converted to PDF by fpdf

Tags: php

I need help on this.
I downloaded fpdf library, and I configured to export MySql data to PDF format by using PHP, and it does very well, but Am stacking on how to shape displayed information to suite my desire.

This is a way it shows information from a table:

```
Micro connection | P.O.Box 123 | Dar es salaam | 0712909858 | mcltz@gmail.com
```

whatever I tried to brake line by using $pdf->Ln(); no any effect appear.

I want information to display like this:

```
Micro connection
P.O.Box 123 Dar es salaam
Mob: 0712909858
Email: mcltz@gmail.com
```

Here the codes:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
require_once("fpdf/dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);

$header = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT name, tin, adress, state, tel, mob,       
email, image FROM company_info");
foreach($header as $heading) {
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Ln();$pdf->Ln();
foreach($heading as $column_heading)
    $pdf->Cell(30,30,$column_heading);
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Any help please:

I fail to bring you here fpdf file, it has alot of codes but u can get it from  http://phppot.com/php/php-pdf-generation-using-fpdf/